# Recursion without Else Statement

Tags: java, recursion

I am just wondering if this is a valid example of recursion without using an else statement. Most recursion examples I have seen use an if-else format. However, my example does not use an else statement. The problem is to fill an array from one index position to another. For example, filling an array with a specified element from position 2 to 5.

```
public static void fill(int[] array, int element, int from, int to) {
   if (from <= to) {
       array[from] = element;
       fill(array, element, from + 1, to)
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a valid recursion since there is no return value. This means that if the condition is not met, there is no more work to do and the method just returns.

If the method had a return value, you'd have to put some return statement in an else clause (or just after the if clause).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a valid way of recursing. Since the return type is `void` there is no need to return a value in the end. Your code is equivalent to:

```
public static void fill(int[] array, int element, int from, int to) {
   if (from <= to) {
       array[from] = element;
       fill(array, element, from + 1, to);
   } else {}
}
```

*However*, if you needed to return a value, then you'd need a meaningful else statement, since all code paths must return a value of the correct type--in your case both the "if" and the "else" branches.

Answer (score 0):

The code is valid and should work. Of course iteration is more appropriate here, but the recursion works as well. When `from > to` your method will end the recursive calling.